# Memory gets full, using Magento in combination with Varnish Cache

Tags: magento-1.9, varnish

We're using CentOS 6.8 with DirectAdmin, Apache 2.4.20, PHP 5.6.22, MySQL 5.6.29 and Magento 1.9.2.1 with all patches included (will be upgraded to 1.9.2.4 once we finished our new webshop but this might take some weeks).

I've installed Varnish and php-redis but don't think all the settings are set right. Memory gets up to 8 while theres 8gb memory inside the server. When I check top, I see many httpd's. Seems like these are staying too long or so. Not sure if this is caused by Varnish? Anyone got ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Surely enough it's not caused by Varnish.
If you're serious about going with Magento store for production - go with at least Apache + **PHP-FPM** (not mod_php) to avoid memory issues.

But overall recommended for production is Varnish + Nginx + PHP-FPM (throw out Apache completely)

Nginx is better, faster than Apache.

I would also remove DirectAdmin and any panel-ware software: these are not needed in real world - you setup server once and live once :) You don't need a constant process nagging your server resources for nothing, or one time when you decide to change a password or create an additional virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

thats correct - memory will run out if you have allocated too much for Varnish and Redis. Varnish by design will double its memory usage.

you can limit in Varnish:

```
-s malloc,1G
```

in Redis:

```
maxmemory 1G
maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
```

also run this to find out mysql memory allocation:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl
```

go to DirectAdmin forum to find out how to change your setup to Apache + PHP-FPM
it will be better on memory management.